# Erro 500 em arquivos php

Tags: php

Colegas.

Tenho uma página em PHP do qual até ontem estava funcionando corretamente, porém hoje está dando erro 500. Já exclui todo o código e deixei apenas a tag de abertura < ? php e mesmo assim o erro persiste, porém quando retiro também a tag, a página aparece (em branco, já que nao mais nada nela). Lembro algum tempo atrás que pode ser o espaço que ocorre antes da tag de abertura, que em determinados programas é possível ver esse espaço, mas nao lembro o nome do programa. Estou usando no Netbeans.

Comment: Pode ser problema com o htaccess ou código, faça um teste no arquivo com problema adicione essas duas linhas `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: `< ? php` tem espaços, tente com `<?php` sem espaço.

Comment: na verdade Lvcs coloquei espaço porque quando publiquei o post, ele não apareceu.

Comment: Coloquei o código, mas mesmo assim dá erro 500

Comment: bem vc editou o seu arquivo no servidor web com usuario root tente mudar a permisssao do seu arquivo

Comment: aparece essa mensagem no log PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function phpini_set()

Comment: Essa função foi criado por vc?

Comment: sim... ele estava funcionando ontem, mas hoje quando acessamos aqui está dando esse erro

Comment: Achei o programa. Ele é um editor binário que ajuda nos espaços que ocorrem antes da tag do php e que muitos editores não conseguem visualizar. Segue o link: http://www.hhdsoftware.com/free-hex-editor

Comment: Porém o código não possui espaços e a página continua dando erro colocando apenas a tag de abertura do php.

Comment: E se comentar a linha do `phpini_set()` o erro para?

Comment: continua... o arquivo só tem a tag < ? php ... nada além disso... muito estranho (a tag é junta, separei devido a problema na hora de postar)

Comment: Há algum .htacess? Se sim publique-o e também o lin que você está tentando acessar

Comment: Entrei em contato com o servidor e eles informaram que o erro foi interno, do qual já foi resolvido. Agradeço aos colegas que prestaram solidariedade com o meu problema.